# Implement OAuth2 with #restsharp into #winforms c# application

Tags: winforms, restsharp

I have to implement OAuth2 authentification into a plain C# .Net Winforms client, to connect to a secured REST API.
API will send me an Access Token.

What is the simplest way to achieve this ? Thank you

I try to use restsharp.